# A problem on proving inner product formula $\langle x,y\rangle=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\langle x,e_k\rangle\overline{\langle y,e_k\rangle}$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces

Let $\{e_k\}_{k\in\Bbb N}$ be orthonormal basis of a inner product space over $\Bbb C$.
I want to prove that $\langle x,y\rangle=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\langle x,e_k\rangle\overline{\langle y,e_k\rangle}$ for $x,~y\in\overline{\text{span}\{e_k\}_{k\in\Bbb N}}$.

My attempt: $x=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\langle x,e_k\rangle e_k$ and $y=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\langle y,e_k\rangle e_k$. Then $$\langle x,y\rangle=\left\langle\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\langle x,e_k\rangle e_k,\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\langle y,e_k\rangle e_k\right\rangle.$$
However, how to move out the $\lim$ symbol? I can't find a way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to move the limit out it suffices to show that the inner product is continuous. From the problem it looks like you're working in a Hilbert space or some related notion, not just an inner product space, over $\mathbb C,$ so you should have some kind of topology on your space already. This topology comes from the metric induced by the inner product, so the inner product is continuous almost by definition. Can you work out the details?

Comment: Yes, hilbert space indeed. I'm familar with the continuity of the norm function $\|\cdot\|:V\to\Bbb R$. But when it comes to inner product case, $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle:V\times V\to\Bbb C$, what does the continuity mean?

Comment: The inner product is a function $V\times V\to \mathbb C$. You give $V\times V$ the product topology and $\mathbb C$ the standard topology. Now we just have two topological spaces, so continuity makes sense. If you're unfamiliar with this terminology, then think of it like this: you need to show that for each $\epsilon>0$ there is some $\delta>0$ such that if $h\in V$ has $|h|<\delta,$ then $|\langle x+h,y\rangle - \langle x,y \rangle|<\epsilon.$ This proves continuity in the first variable. The second variable is similar, and then you're done.

Comment: I see! So the rest steps are $\langle x,y\rangle=\left\langle\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\langle x,e_k\rangle e_k,\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\langle y,e_k\rangle e_k\right\rangle=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left\langle\sum_{k=1}^n\langle x,e_k\rangle e_k,\sum_{k=1}^n\langle y,e_k\rangle e_k\right\rangle=\cdots\text{some computation}\cdots=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\langle x,e_k\rangle\overline{\langle y,e_k\rangle}$

Comment: Once you have continuity, yes that should be it.